# Prove that $A\int_0^\infty S(t) u dt=\int_0^\infty S(t) A u dt$ if A is a closed operator

Tags: operator-theory

From Wikipedia:

> Closed linear operators are a class of linear operators on Banach
>   spaces. They are more general than bounded operators, and therefore
>   not necessarily continuous, but they still retain nice enough
>   properties that one can define the spectrum and (with certain
>   assumptions) functional calculus for such operators. Many important
>   linear operators which fail to be bounded turn out to be closed, such
>   as the derivative and a large class of differential operators.

Let X Banach space, and $D(A) ⊂ X$ the domain of operator A.

A linear operator A : $D(A) ⊂ X → X$ is closed if for every sequence $\{u_k\}$ in $D(A)$ converging to $u$ in X such that $A u_k → v ∈ X$ as $k → ∞$ one has $u ∈ D(A)$ and $A u = v$.

Prove that, if A is closed, then

$$A\int_0^\infty S(t) u dt=\int_0^\infty S(t) A u dt$$

where $S: X\rightarrow X$ is any function such that the integral is defined, i.e. $u\in D(A)$, S such that $S(t)u\in D(A)$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Is $S$ a real-valued (or complex-valued) function? If so, this should be true even without the closedness assumption.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: Is $u \in D(A)$? Is $S$ such that $S(t)u \in D(A)$ for all $t>0$? Otherwise, the l.h.s and the r.h.s., respectively, are not well defined.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I will modify my post again